# Using command line to bypass "Missing parentheses in call to 'print'"

Tags: command-line, python, printing, python3

I have a foo.py Python file containing `print "bar"` code.
When I want to `python foo.py` my code, here is the error : `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'`. Do you know how to avoid this error without adding '(' and ')' to  my `print` function ?

Thanks !

Comment: For python 3 print is a function and must have ()

Answer (score 0):

If your script is compatible then you can force use of Python2 by running it something like

`python2 foo.py`

or

`python2.7 foo.py`

That is, of course, to purely answer your question as to "using the command line to bypass" the issue.

A rewrite of the code for either 2-and-3 compatibility, using 2to3 for conversion, or refactoring for Python3 would be the other non-command-line approach.